# how to install opencv-python on linux with requirements.txt

Tags: python, opencv, lib

I'm trying to deploy a python bot that use opencv on discloud but when I start the app it show the error:

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
E  File "/home/user_1028648117500924025/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
X  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
Y  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
3    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
U  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
@    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
SImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```